# transitioning from r to Python - dplyr-like operations in pandas

Tags: python, r, pandas, dplyr

I'm used to using R.  If I had this in R I would do something like this:

```
     library(dplyr)
df = df %>% 
mutate(
     XYZ = sum(x+y+z),
     weekcheck = ifelse( week > 3 & X*2 > 4, 'yes',week), # multi-step if statement          
      XYZ_plus_3 = XYZ + 3
       )

df = pd.DataFrame({
            'x': np.random.uniform(1., 168., 20),
            'y': np.random.uniform(7., 334., 20),
            'z': np.random.uniform(1.7, 20.7, 20),
            'month': [5,6,7,8]*5,
            'week': np.random.randint(1,4, 20)
            })
```

I know theres assign but I can't figure out the syntax for chaining these operations together, particularly using IFELSE sort of thing.

Anyone attempt to break this down for me?  Even if you don't know R I think the code is fairly common sense..

Answer (score 2):

You'd need two assign calls for that and the syntax is not as pretty:

```
(df.assign(XYZ=df[['x', 'y', 'z']].sum(axis=1), 
           weekcheck=np.where((df['week']>3) & (df['x']*2>4), 'yes', df['week']))
   .assign(XYZ_plus_3=lambda d: d['XYZ']+3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but I would do it like this in pandas.  In particular, I think that `np.where()` is a direct analog to R's `ifelse` (I don't know R very well though).  There may be similar way to do this in pandas but I've always found `np.where()` to be the fastest and most general approach.

```
df['xyz']    = df.x + df.y + df.z
df['wcheck'] = np.where( (df.week>2) & (df.x*2>4), 'yes', df.week )
df['xyz_p3'] = df.xyz + 3

   week           x           y          z         xyz wcheck      xyz_p3
0     2    1.968759   31.537797  18.984273   52.490830      2   55.490830
1     1  108.809481  295.126414  14.250059  418.185954      1  421.185954
2     3  124.094087  201.229196  15.346794  340.670077    yes  343.670077
3     2  122.874717  110.675192   6.179610  239.729519      2  242.729519
4     1   74.909326   12.484076   4.921888   92.315290      1   95.315290
```

You could do some or all of this as a method chain, although I don't see a particular advantage here beyond making the code a little more compact and clean (not that I am knocking that!).  But much of the difference is just three lines vs "one line" that is spread across three lines...

I dunno, YMMV, but a lot of this comes down to specific examples and in this case I would just do it in three separate lines of pandas as opposed to figuring out how to do it as a method chain with `assign` or `pipe`.

Comment: For this particular example, since the else part is `df.week`, you can use either `Series.mask` or `Series.where` on `week` column but there isn't a equivalent of np.where.

Comment: @ayhan, thanks, that's what I thought.  I generally stick to np.where for exactly that reason as I don't have to worry if df.where will work or not.

Comment: @JohnE  I will take a look at this tomorrow.   I was just throwing out a random example off the top of my head where it is extremely easy with R -dplyr syntax to perform a variety of functions across groups of data and functions.  I'm trying to get a sense of what that would like in pandas or python in general

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you'd do it with [datar](https://github.com/datar), a python package that ports dplyr and other packages into python, and follows their API design:

```py
In [1]: from datar.all import *

In [2]: df = tibble(
   ...:     x=runif(20, 1., 168.),
   ...:     y=runif(20, 7., 334.),
   ...:     z=runif(20, 1.7, 20.7),
   ...:     month=[5,6,7,8]*5,
   ...:     week=rnorm(20, 1, 4)
   ...: )

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
             x           y          z  month      week
0   122.186045  210.469468   3.685605      5  2.832896
1   165.584417  328.907586   8.535625      6 -0.277586
2    47.149510  205.991526   8.302771      7 -3.212263
3    88.110641  137.452398  11.920447      8 -3.307180
4   157.378195  215.928386  19.047386      5  0.442600
5   115.881867  122.972666  20.367191      6 -2.810770
6    70.939125  303.212096   2.864381      7  1.676704
7   124.173937  159.179588  16.231502      8 -1.431897
8    67.049824  266.658257   2.483528      5 -4.815040
9   165.531614  315.180892  13.855680      6  4.094581
10   59.077945   87.218260  10.638067      7 -0.204437
11  160.982998  320.093002   9.470513      8 -1.877375
12   23.520600  143.737008   1.989666      5  2.344435
13   26.028670  261.396529  19.844300      6  1.956208
14  100.008859  261.133030  15.947817      7  3.202203
15  102.298540   29.667462   4.470771      8 -4.747893
16   38.565169  239.578190  11.088213      5  0.268926
17   73.553130   49.714928   4.449677      6 -3.592172
18   74.467545   16.350189   8.195442      7  3.451417
19  162.439950  189.721896   7.729186      8  4.486240

In [4]: df >> rowwise() >> mutate(
   ...:     XYZ=sum(f.x+f.y+f.z),
   ...:     weekcheck=if_else((f.week > 3) & (f.x*2 > 4), 'yes', f.week),
   ...:     XYZ_plus_3=f.XYZ+3
   ...: )
Out[4]: 
             x           y          z  month      week         XYZ weekcheck  XYZ_plus_3
0   122.186045  210.469468   3.685605      5  2.832896  336.341118  2.832896  339.341118
1   165.584417  328.907586   8.535625      6 -0.277586  503.027628 -0.277586  506.027628
2    47.149510  205.991526   8.302771      7 -3.212263  261.443807 -3.212263  264.443807
3    88.110641  137.452398  11.920447      8 -3.307180  237.483487  -3.30718  240.483487
4   157.378195  215.928386  19.047386      5  0.442600  392.353967    0.4426  395.353967
5   115.881867  122.972666  20.367191      6 -2.810770  259.221724  -2.81077  262.221724
6    70.939125  303.212096   2.864381      7  1.676704  377.015603  1.676704  380.015603
7   124.173937  159.179588  16.231502      8 -1.431897  299.585026 -1.431897  302.585026
8    67.049824  266.658257   2.483528      5 -4.815040  336.191610  -4.81504  339.191610
9   165.531614  315.180892  13.855680      6  4.094581  494.568187       yes  497.568187
10   59.077945   87.218260  10.638067      7 -0.204437  156.934272 -0.204437  159.934272
11  160.982998  320.093002   9.470513      8 -1.877375  490.546514 -1.877375  493.546514
12   23.520600  143.737008   1.989666      5  2.344435  169.247274  2.344435  172.247274
13   26.028670  261.396529  19.844300      6  1.956208  307.269499  1.956208  310.269499
14  100.008859  261.133030  15.947817      7  3.202203  377.089707       yes  380.089707
15  102.298540   29.667462   4.470771      8 -4.747893  136.436772 -4.747893  139.436772
16   38.565169  239.578190  11.088213      5  0.268926  289.231572  0.268926  292.231572
17   73.553130   49.714928   4.449677      6 -3.592172  127.717735 -3.592172  130.717735
18   74.467545   16.350189   8.195442      7  3.451417   99.013176       yes  102.013176
19  162.439950  189.721896   7.729186      8  4.486240  359.891031       yes  362.891031
[Rowwise: []]
```

I am the author of the package. Feel free to submit issues or ask me questions about using it.